# How to change mimetype image for PSD file (Photoshop)?

Tags: 10.10, icons, mime-type, photoshop

Following this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes, I first typed a command to discover the mimetype for psd extension

```
~$ grep 'psd' /etc/mime.types 
image/x-photoshop       psd
```

Then I took Photoshop CS5 SVG image from Wikipedia and renamed it to `image-x-photoshop.svg`. Then I copied the file to the folder `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable` via command

```
sudo cp image-x-photoshop.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/image-x-photoshop.svg
```

Loogged out, logged in, but the icon for the .psd files is still unchanged.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: OP did you find a solution? if yes, post it as an answer here.

Comment: @Mahesh No. Neither works yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `image-x-photoshop.svg` in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes` not `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/`

Comment: Tried this just now. Logged out and in, but nothing happens. The .psd file still does not have this icon.

Comment: Thats interesting. I wonder if there could be something wrong with the svg file your using.

Comment: I found it via Google Images. Do you want me to give you its url? Should svg file be of some specific size? Like max size I should not go over?